# Probability and sample space of game.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I solved (partial) exercise from W. Feller book but I don't know whether my solution is OK.

**Rules of the game:**
Three players **a**,**b** and **c** play the some game. First **a** plays with **b** and **c** waits. After game **c** plays with winner of first game etc. Game ends after one of the players wins two games in row. We have two sequences of game:

**aa**, **acc**, **acbb**, **acbaa**, **acbacc**, **acbacbb**, **acbacbaa**, ...
**bb**, **bcc**, **bcaa**, **bcabb**, **bcabcc**, **bcabcaa**, **bcabcabb**, ...

For each game We have two possibilities of winner. So sequence contains $k$ symbols has probability $2^{-k}$. But only two sequences means end of the game. Probabilities are well defined, because sum of all possibilities is equal 1.

$$
\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{2}{2^i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1
$$

Sequences contains win of **a** are as below:

**aa**, **acbaa**, **acbacbaa** - From first sequence
**bcaa**, **bcabcaa**, **bcabcabcaa** - From second sequence

So We can calculate probability of win of **a** player.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2+3i}}+\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{4+3i}}=\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}\right)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{8^i}=\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}\right)\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{8}}= \frac{5}{14}
$$

For **b** it will be the same. For **c** - $\frac{2}{7}$.

Exercise consist in add draw (**r**). When draw is added, then sequences has below forms ($k$ is length of sequence):

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
k & sequences & amount \\
\hline
2 & aa;\, bb & 2 \\
\hline
3 & acc;\, bcc;\, raa;\, ara;\, rbb;\, brb & 6\\
\hline
4 & acbb;\, bcaa;\, rraa;\, rara;\, rrbb;\, rbrb;\, arra;\, brrb;\, racc;\, rbcc;\, arcc;\, brcc;\, acrc;\, bcrc & 14\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

I can count sequences with length $k$ using this method:

Get sequence with length 2 (e.g. **aa**). Put last letter on the end of $k$-length sequence and choose one of $k-1$ places for second letter. We have ${k-1}\choose{1}$ possibilities. Too same for **bb** so We need to multiple it by 2. For **acc** sequence, We need to put last letter on the end and select 2 of $k-1$ places for two remaining letters - ${k-1}\choose{2}$ possibilities. Activities ends when We have no places for draw, so on ${k-1}\choose{k-1}$. All expressions need to be multiplied by 2.

$$
2\left({{k-1}\choose{1}}+\cdots+{{k-1}\choose{k-1}}\right)=2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{{k-1}\choose{i}}-{{k-1}\choose{0}}\right)=2^k-2
$$

Games result can be one of playing players or it can be draw, so We can three possibilities of end. In this case We have probability of $k$-length sequence equal $3^{-k}$. Probability of end of game in $k$ steps $p_k$ is equal:

$$
p_k=\frac{2^k-2}{3^k}
$$

It seems that this result is OK, because sum for all $k=1,2,3,...$ is equal 1.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{2^i-2}{3^i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^i-2\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^i}=\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{2}{3}}-2\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=1
$$

Is my result OK? How can I calculate probabilities for particular player?

Thanks! :) and sorry for my English.